# I need to use NTP to serve a time offset from system time. Is broadcast the way to go?

Tags: time, ntp

I have a closed network with a few nodes that are mutually consistent in time. For this I use NTP with one node as the NTP server. One of the nodes is a dumb box over which I have little control. It runs an sntp client to synchronize time to the system NTP server. I now need the box to be set to a time that is offset from the system time by an amount that I control. I am trying to find out if this can be done using only the available sntp client on the box. I will now present you my approach and would love to hear from anyone who knows if this can be done.

As far as I found out a standard NTP server cannot be made to serve a time that is offset from the server's system time. I will therefore have to write my own implementation. The conceptually simplest NTP server must be a broadcast-only server. My thought is that I will be able to set the sntp box to listen to broadcast and then just send NTP broadcast packets set to my custom time.

Are there any NTP server implementations that allow me to do this out of the box?

Can anyone tell me how hard it is to write an sNTP broadcast server - or any other NTP server?

Does anyone know of any tutorials for how to write an NTP server?

Are there any show-stoppers to the scheme I am describing above?

To try to answer the questions that will inevitably come up:

- Yes, I am also thinking about a new interface on the box to set the time to a value I specify. But that is not what I am asking about, and no, it will not be much simpler.
- I have inverstigated if I could just use the time that the box needs as the system time. This is not an option. I will need two different times, one for the system and one for the box.

All insight will be appreciated! Even opinions like "it should be doable."

Answer (score 0):

You could use Jans to serve a fake time. I have no experience with this product but I know of it from the ntp mailing list. It will allow you to server faketime but it does none of the clock discipline like the reference implementation.

More info: http://www.vanheusden.com/time/jans/

Answer (score 0):

Jans on its own is not suitable to provide fake time with offset, but it can provide real time plus a lot of test functionality like time drift, so on.
I used Jans as the source of real time in conjunction with llibfaketime on linux CentOs 6 as fake NTP server with + or - offset.
Just wget jans-0.3.tgz and run "make" from here:
https://www.vanheusden.com/time/jans/

RPM of libfaketime for CentOs 6 is here:
http://rpm.pbone.net/info_idpl_54489387_distro_centos6_com_libfaketime-0.9.7-1.1.x86_64.rpm.html

or find it for your distro.
Stop real NTP server if its running on your linux:
`service ntpd stop`

Run fake NTP server (for examle 15 days in the past):
`LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib64/libfaketime.so.1 FAKETIME="-15d" ./jans -P 123 -t real`
Keep in mind that NTP server can be running only on port 123, otherwise you should use iptables masquerading.